# Custom UITableView section header alpha 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

I have implemented a custom section header for a `UITableView`. It works fine except for when I insert a section in the tableview. Then it completely disappears, if I debug I can see that the `alpha` property of the custom section header is `0` which I of course have not set.

This is what I'm doing when the custom header disappears:

```
[self.settingsTableView beginUpdates];

[self.settingsTableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[self.settingsTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[self.settingsTableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*reload* should not be called inside `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem when using a custom header and returning a local ivar instance.

The problem is that UITableView expects for you to return a different view in:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

I think it considers it has 2 views and will set the alpha to 1 and alpha to 0 to the old one... but in my case the "new one" remained with the wrong alpha.

The solution was to just instantiate a new view in that view for section delegate method.